# SQL: Opencart Range Filter

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart2.x

I have made a little extension to "Filter" module in opencart.
But still have a small problem.

My current SQL:

```
SELECT product.product_id FROM `oc_product` product
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_attribute` attribute ON product.product_id = attribute.product_id
WHERE 
((attribute.attribute_id = 13 (weight) AND `text` BETWEEN 1 AND 2) 
OR (attribute.attribute_id = 12 (length) AND `text` BETWEEN 10 AND 12));
```

But this returns things between 1 and 2 (weight) along with between 10 and 12 (length). So for example, something weights 2kg gets returned and something that is 11cm long get returned.

I want it to return something that would both, for example, weigh 2kg and be 11cm long.

I have tried putting `AND` between conditions, but it doesn't return anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation and having clause to get the product_ids that satisfy both the criteria:

```
select p.product_id 
from oc_product p
left join oc_product_attribute a on p.product_id = a.product_id
group by p.product_id
having sum(a.attribute_id = 13 and text between 1 and 2) > 0
   and sum(a.attribute_id = 12 and text between 10 and 12) > 0;
```